# Python 2.7: xml.sax._exceptions.SAXReaderNotAvailable: No parsers found

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing, py2exe

I found a strange thing. When I'm running a python code via PyCharm, my app works fine. But when I do an exe file via py2exe app is crashing with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in CreateNewClientRequest
  File "suds\client.pyc", line 112, in __init__
  File "suds\reader.pyc", line 152, in open
  File "suds\wsdl.pyc", line 136, in __init__
  File "suds\reader.pyc", line 79, in open
  File "suds\reader.pyc", line 101, in download
  File "suds\sax\parser.pyc", line 127, in parse
  File "suds\sax\parser.pyc", line 111, in saxparser
  File "xml\sax\sax2exts.pyc", line 37, in make_parser
  File "xml\sax\saxexts.pyc", line 77, in make_parser
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXReaderNotAvailable: No parsers found
```

Does anyone knows how to fix that?
Here is the sample of my a python code (may be it can helps):

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import sys, xml
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from window import Ui_SmartRequest
from suds.client import Client

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_SmartRequest()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btn.clicked.connect(self.CreateNewClientRequest)

    def CreateNewClientRequest(self):
        shop = self.ui.shop_line.text()
        shop1 = "%s" %shop
        card_id = self.ui.card_line.text()
        card_id1 = "%s" %card_id
        anketa = self.ui.anketa_line.text()
        anketa1 = "%s" %anketa
        client = Client('http://172.16.0.37:8000/CardPort?wsdl')
        out = client.service.CreateNewClientRequest(shop1, card_id1, anketa1)
        out1 = "%s" %out
        out2 = str(out1[19:38])
        out3 = out2.replace("}", "")
        self.ui.line_out.setText("Code:"+out3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And also the code from setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    windows=[{"script":"main.py"}],
    options={"py2exe": {"includes":["PyQt4","sip","suds","sys","os","wstools","defusedxml", "xml.sax"]}},
    zipfile=None

)
```

I will be happy if some one helps me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting

File "xml\sax\saxexts.pyc", line 77, in make_parser
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXReaderNotAvailable: No parsers found
Try adding this to your setup.py py2exe command line:

```
--packages xml.sax.drivers,xml.sax.drivers2
```

source: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyXML

Comment: [link](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/py2exeAndSOAPpy) - solved here. @FrEaKmAn "thanks"